# Why thread stuck?

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, libcurl

I'm implementing a multiple threads download manager on Windows using C++.

The main thread starts download manage thread M, M starts several download threads D.
Each D will do the HTTP data transfer using [library cpr](https://docs.libcpr.org/) which is a wrapper around [libcurl](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/).

After starts some D threads, M enters a loop, keep watching the download progress.

The strange thing: once the second D started, or I abort the first D by return error code(an integer other then 0, I return 1.) from the libcurl's CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION callback, M's loop will stop. (There's one debugging output inside M's loop. I notice its stop by the disappear of that output from console. Maybe it's not stop, just going into some waiting state instead...)

Both M and D thread are started by STL's std::thread.

Have been scratched by this problem a whole day. Any clue will be appreciated...

---

This is the M thread entrance:

```
void HttpDownloader1::MasterThreadFunc_()
{
int loop_count = 0;

// start the first download thread
if (!SplitDownload_(nullptr))
{
    status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
    return;
}

uint64_t prev_downloaded_bytes = recorder_->GetDownloadedBytes();

for (loop_count = 0; download_threads_.size() > 0; loop_count++)
//while (true)
{
    loop_count++;
#ifdef _DEBUG
    Debug_("main loop, threads: " + std::to_string(download_threads_.size()));
#endif
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500)); // 0.5s

    DownloadThread* splitable_segment = nullptr;
    auto it = download_threads_.begin();

    while (it != download_threads_.end())
    {
        DownloadThread* thread = *it;

        if (thread->status_ == Status::FINISH)
        {
            delete thread;
            it = download_threads_.erase(it);
        }
        else
        {
            switch (thread->status_)
            {
            case Status::RUNNING:
            default:
                recorder_->MarkFinish(thread->begin_, thread->pos_ - 1);
                // part of this segment may have been splited to other download thread
                //thread->end_ = recorder_->GetSegmentEnd(thread->pos_);
                break;

            case Status::SUCCESSFUL:
                if (recorder_->IsInitialized())
                {
                    thread->CloseFile();
                    recorder_->MarkFinish(thread->begin_, thread->pos_ - 1);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (!PrepareFile_(*it))
                        status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
                }
                splitable_segment = *it;
                break;

            case Status::ERRONEOUS:
                if (++retry_ > kMaxHttpRetry)
                {
                    status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
                }
                else
                {
                    thread->CloseFile();
                    recorder_->MarkFailed(thread->pos_, thread->end_);
                    splitable_segment = *it;
                }
                break;
            }
            it++;
        }
    }

    // break out if error occured
    if (status_ == Status::ERRONEOUS)
    {
        break;
    }

    // if download completed
    if (recorder_->IsFinish())
    {
        status_ = Status::SUCCESSFUL;
        break;
    }

    // calculate download speed every 1 second 
    if ((loop_count & 1) == 1)
    {
        auto bytes = recorder_->GetDownloadedBytes();
        bytes_per_second_ = bytes - prev_downloaded_bytes;
        prev_downloaded_bytes = bytes;
    }

    // save progress info every 2 seconds
    if ((loop_count & 3) == 3)
    {
        recorder_->Save();
    }

    // split download when any thread is available or every 4 seconds
    if (splitable_segment || (loop_count & 7) == 7)
    {
        if (splitable_segment != nullptr)
            SplitDownload_(splitable_segment);
        else if (download_threads_.size() < max_threads_)
            SplitDownload_(nullptr);
    }
}

master_thread_.detach();
status_ = status_ != Status::ERRONEOUS ? Status::SUCCESSFUL : status_;
}
```

---

This is how M start D thread:

```
bool HttpDownloader1::SplitDownload_(DownloadThread* thread)
{
if (!recorder_->IsInitialized())
{
    if (!thread)
        thread = CreateDownloadThread_();
    thread->begin_ = 0;
    thread->end_ = 0;
}
else
{
    int64_t begin, end;
    if (recorder_->GetTask(&begin, &end)) 
    {
        // initialize this segment
        if (!thread)
            thread = CreateDownloadThread_();

        thread->begin_ = begin;
        thread->end_ = end;
        thread->pos_ = thread->begin_;

        if (thread->file_ == nullptr)
        {
            //errno_t e = fopen_s(&thread->file_, target_.GetPath().c_str(), "rb+");
            thread->file_ = fopen(target_.GetPath().c_str(), "rb+");
            //if (e == 0 && thread->file_)
            if (thread->file_)
            {
                fseek(thread->file_, (long)thread->begin_, SEEK_SET);
            }
            else
            {
                thread->status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        // no more segment to download or split, remove this thread if it exists.
        if (thread)
            thread->status_ = Status::FINISH;
    }
}

if (thread && thread->status_ != Status::FINISH)
{
    thread->status_ = Status::RUNNING;
    thread->thread_ = std::thread(&HttpDownloader1::DownloadThreadFunc_, this, thread);
    thread->thread_.detach();
}
return true;
}
```

---

This is the D thread entrance:

```
void HttpDownloader1::DownloadThreadFunc_(DownloadThread* thread)
{
cpr::Response rsp;
if (thread->file_ == nullptr)
{
    rsp = cpr::Get(
        cpr::Url(target_.url_.c_str()),
        cpr::ConnectTimeout(std::chrono::seconds(kConnectionTimeout)),
        cpr::Timeout(std::chrono::seconds(kTransmitTimeout)),
        cpr::VerifySsl(false),
        cpr::Header{ { "Range", thread->GetRangeHeaderString().c_str() } },
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 1 }),
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, nullptr }),
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &HttpDownloader1::WriteCallback_ })
    );
}
else
{
    rsp = cpr::Get(
        cpr::Url(target_.url_.c_str()),
        cpr::ConnectTimeout(std::chrono::seconds(kConnectionTimeout)),
        cpr::Timeout(std::chrono::seconds(kTransmitTimeout)),
        cpr::VerifySsl(false),
        cpr::Header{ { "Range", thread->GetRangeHeaderString().c_str() } },
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0 }),
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_XFERINFODATA, thread }),
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_XFERINFOFUNCTION, &HttpDownloader1::ProgressCallback_ }),
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, thread->file_ }),
        cpr::CurlOption({ CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, fwrite })
    );

}

if (rsp.status_code == 0)
{
    thread->status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
    Log_("thread:" + std::to_string(thread->id_) + " error: HTTP status code 0");
}
else if (rsp.status_code >= 400)
{
    thread->status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
    Log_("thread:" + std::to_string(thread->id_) + " erorr: HTTP status code " + std::to_string(rsp.status_code));
}
else if (rsp.error.code != cpr::ErrorCode::OK)
{
    thread->status_ = Status::ERRONEOUS;
    Log_("thread:" + std::to_string(thread->id_) + "error: " + rsp.error.message);
}
else
{
    if (thread->file_ == nullptr)
        thread->response_header_ = rsp.header;
    thread->status_ = Status::SUCCESSFUL;
}
}
```

---

This is libcurl's progress callback:

```
int HttpDownloader1::ProgressCallback_(
void* clientp, std::uint64_t dltotal, std::uint64_t dlnow, std::uint64_t ultotal, std::uint64_t ulnow
) {
auto thread = (DownloadThread*)clientp;
if (dlnow > 0)
{
    thread->pos_ = thread->begin_ + dlnow;

    if (thread->pos_ > thread->end_)
        return 1;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It could be usefull to see the main code that launches the threads or important exception spots where could help us help you.

Comment: You haven't shared any code or debugging details on what thread M is doing when it appears to be stuck. In particular, you haven't explained how each download thread D signals thread M that it has completed.

Comment: @RicardoOrtegaMagaña Code posted!

Comment: @RaymondChen Code  posted!

Comment: Where does thread M get stuck? Are the members of `thread` atomic? If not, then you have data races and the behavior is undefined. Also, my guess is that `CreateDownloadThread_` modifies `download_threads_`, and I'm guessing that `download_threads_` is a `std::vector`, in which case you are modifying the length of a vector which invalidates iterators.

Comment: Use the debugger to attach to the process and see what the main thread is doing.

Comment: @RaymondChen 1. I'm not clear where does M get stuck yet. Because when I debug it step by step, everything is fine. If let it run, when the loop stop, no break point will get hit. 2. D thread write ```thread->status_``` field which is ```uint8_t``` type and which is read by M thread inside the loop.  And the progress callback write ```thread->pos_``` which is ```std::atomic_uint64```. 3. ```download_threads_``` is a std::list, there do have the problem that ```CreateDownloadThread_``` modifying the length within iteration. But when I change the D thread number to 1, M still get stuck.

Comment: A [mre] would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer: Because I made a stupid mistake...**

**Details:**
The M thread didn't got stuck(halt abnormally), it's just in a dead loop.
The loop isn't in the main loop of M, but inside the `recorder_->MarkFinish(...)` call, where I forgot incrementing the iterator at one of the `if branch` when loop a list container by `while(...) {...}`.

So when I placed a breakpoint at the `recorder_->MarkFinish()` line, it wouldn't be caught.

**How I found that eventually:**
I don't have much experience at multiple thread programming. After scratching my head for nearly a whole day, I thought there must be some low level details unfamiliar to me. So I post this question.

*@Raymond* comments brought back my confidence. I begun to add debug outputs line by line inside the M thread's main loop trying to find out what it was doing when it seemed stuck. And noticed that each time the error occurred, the outputs would disappear right after that `recorder_->MarkFinish(...)` call. So I went into that function and caught the carelessly code bellow:

```
while (it != segments_.end())
{
    Segment& seg = *it;

    if (seg.begin_ > end) break;
    if (seg.end_ < start) continue; // ！
    
    if (start <= seg.begin_ && seg.begin_ <= end)
        seg.begin_ = end + 1;
    if (start <= seg.end_ && seg.end_ <= end)
        seg.end_ = start - 1;

    if (seg.end_ < seg.begin_)
        it = segments_.erase(it);
    else
        it++;
}
```

Hope this might help reducing some of the mysterious sense about the problem you meet.